# Error while duplicating Oracle database after failover, using 11.2.0.4

Tags: oracle, failover, rman, duplication, dataguard

I've recently updated oracle from version `11.2.0.1` to `11.2.0.4` and my redundant system is no longer able to recover from failover.

I'm using scripts both on primary and standby node to get back to a state where it is possible to install them as a redundant system again.

It is possible to run the reset script over and over again in all states exept after a failover is performed. The only change is the upgrade to `11.2.0.4.` it worked like a charm in `11.2.0.1`

I am using Data Guard Broker to maintan the redundancy.

The setup procedure is complicated and is hard to explain here, so I am just asking if someone have faced the same error, and might have a solution how to recover from such situation.

At least, this is the output where it fails: (Backup step is performed prior to duplicate action)

```
2014-11-14 17:08:55 : Recovery Manager: Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on Fri Nov 14 17:08:48 2014
2014-11-14 17:08:55 : Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
2014-11-14 17:08:55 : connected to target database: REF15 (DBID=276671931)
2014-11-14 17:08:55 : RMAN> CONNECT AUXILIARY *
2014-11-14 17:08:55 : 2> RUN {
2014-11-14 17:08:55 : 3> SET UNTIL sequence = 159 thread = 1;
2014-11-14 17:08:55 : 4> ALLOCATE AUXILIARY CHANNEL CH1 TYPE DISK;
2014-11-14 17:08:55 : 5> DUPLICATE TARGET DATABASE FOR STANDBY NOFILENAMECHECK DORECOVER;
2014-11-14 17:08:56 : 6> RELEASE CHANNEL CH1;
2014-11-14 17:08:56 : 7> }
2014-11-14 17:08:56 : 8> exit;
2014-11-14 17:08:56 : connected to auxiliary database: REF15 (not mounted)
2014-11-14 17:08:56 : executing command: SET until clause
2014-11-14 17:08:56 : using target database control file instead of recovery catalog
2014-11-14 17:08:56 : allocated channel: CH1
2014-11-14 17:08:56 : channel CH1: SID=25 device type=DISK
2014-11-14 17:08:56 : Starting Duplicate Db at 14-NOV-14
2014-11-14 17:08:56 : released channel: CH1
2014-11-14 17:08:56 : RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
2014-11-14 17:08:56 : RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
2014-11-14 17:08:56 : RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
2014-11-14 17:08:56 : RMAN-03002: failure of Duplicate Db command at 11/14/2014 17:08:51
2014-11-14 17:08:56 : RMAN-05501: aborting duplication of target database
2014-11-14 17:08:56 : RMAN-20206: log sequence not found in the repository
2014-11-14 17:08:56 : Recovery Manager complete.
```

Update:
Log sequence number (in this case: 159) is fetched from the following query:

```
    select max(sequence#) from v$archived_log;
```

Thanks (originally posted in std Stack Exchange)

Comment: Have you tried doing it without the UNTIL clause?  The example here (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41134/rcmbackp.htm#SBYDB4989) doesn't use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message indicates that no archivelog exists with this sequence in the current incarnation.

Failover starts a new incarnation, and log sequences start from 1 again. Let's say your database is at sequence 10 now, and the log sequence was 159 before the failover. V$ARCHIVED_LOG at this point still contains entries about previous incarnation, so the above query will return 159 because it doesn't consider the start of a new incarnation (resetlogs).

For these kind of queries always check resetlogs_change# or resetlogs_time, e.g:

```
select max(sequence#) from v$archived_log join v$database using (resetlogs_change#);
```

Fix this and try duplicating again. Or just skip the UNTIL clause and let log shipping take care of the archivelogs.

Comment: Thanks. It solved my issue. I extended my query to include the Join, and now it selects a better sequence number!